# No launcher icon

Tags: android, menu, icons, launcher, invisible

I have an interesting problem - at least for me.
I don't want my application to have a launcher icon in the menu - I start it remotely and I don't want to show it up in the menu.

How can I solve that?

My idea is deleting the following from the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Would this solve my problem?

Comment: What happened when you removed those lines and reinstalled the application? :)

Comment: Hmm, it is working :) - the idea came while writing the question and I did not try it. But is this a good solution? I feel it to be a little bungle

Comment: When you install the application Android will look for an Activity with that specific `intent-filter` to show in the launcher application as an entry point for your application. If it doesn't find one it doesn't show anything in the launcher.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just thought it will keep searching anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what i would do. This  defines the gateway activity to your application and doesn't affect the functionality. If no activity has this filter, there won't be an icon to launch it manually, precisely what you want.

Comment: Android studio won't compile if there no LAUNCHER category

Answer (score 5):

Delete that:

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

And you won't have a launcher icon.

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13552763/6481542 is correct, but to address the Android Studio compilation issue noted in the comments, you need to modify the Run Configuration in Android Studio:

- Go to Run -> Edit Configurations
- Under Launch Options, change Launch from `Default Activity` to any of the other options.  Using `Specified Activity` with one of your activities is a suitable approach.

This works with Android Studio 2.2.3.